# Specify height of UIToolbar in Storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, interface-builder, uistoryboard, uitoolbar

[image]

When I try to change the height of a UIToolbar through Storyboard, the option is greyed out.

I'm aware I can do this programatically, but is there any alternative way to do it on my storyboard, perhaps by using a different interface item? It'd be better to have it all on storyboard, to avoid code confusion. Or should I not be changing the height - is that likely to get it rejected from the app store?

My end goal is a toolbar with 50 x 50 image icons on, and a bit of padding.

N.B. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196659/) - but here, the accepted answer doesn't seem to actually answer the question...

Comment: I could change the height of a segment control by adding a height constraint ( using auto layout ). Can you check if this works for you?

Comment: Yes, it did! Even more infuriating...if you can 'force' it in like that, why not allow it by default! Thanks a lot - if you want to post that as a full answer, I'll accept! @RainerSchwarze

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use auto layout, you could set a Height Constraint. This worked for me on a `UISegmentedControl`, but I did not test it on a `UIToolbar`.

Comment: In case you like to take a look at my orginal problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21603430/1396265 . Apparently the segmented control causes some issues with auto layout when using a navigation controller :-) Unfortunately I couldn't fix my problem with an IB-only solution...

Comment: Ugh - horrible! Fortunately this is app is for internal company use, so I can essentially specify iOS7 only. Cheers!